# Magnifier glass effect for PDF's in React

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I was trying to implement magnifying glass effect for PDFs in a react application. To display the pdf I used [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf). Effect that required displayed below. Is there any good package or work around that I could use here?

[image]